# How to set stored procedure parameter for may or may not pass the values by user?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, where-clause

User may or may not pass the values in stored procedure values in SQL Stored Procedure

So how to declare my variable in StoredProcedure and how to define in Where clause?

**Example**

```
CREATE PROC spGetRecord
@Storeid nchar(10)=null
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ID,NAME
    FROM table1
    WHERE StoreID=@Storeid    //@Storeid is may pass the value by user or may not
END
```

So how should I define `@Storeid` in Where clause

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing you are building some sort of search procedure...

A simple start, check that the parameter either matches `Storeid`, or that the parameter is `null`:

```
create proc spGetRecord (@Storeid nchar(10)=null) as
begin
  set nocount, xact_abort on;

  select id,name
  from table1
  where (Storeid=@Storeid or @Storeid is null)
end;
```

For more advanced catch-all search queries, see the following:

- [Dynamic Search Conditions - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)
- [Catch-all queries - Gail Shaw](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/)
- [An Updated "Kitchen Sink" Example - Aaron Bertand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example/)
- [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)

Comment: can you give explanation for this line `set nocount, xact_abort on;` ?

Comment: @mohamedfaiz The best explanation is here: [Why you should always include `set xact_abort, nocount on;` - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpXACT_ABORT). It is a good practice (imho best practice) to include it in your procedures for many reasons. Granted, you probably would not need `xact_abort` for a `select` operation, but it doesn't hurt. `nocount` "suppresses messages like (1 row(s) affected) ... [which] degrade performance in an application because of the increased network traffic."